# Meaning of paint out

Tags: meaning

I came across with the following sentence while reading my book;

*George O.may paints out the following major users of financial statements*

What is the meaning of *paints out* here?

Comment: Did you try to look it up in a [dictionary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/paint%20out)?

Comment: @ArmenԾիրունյան Not going to help if he has the wrong word.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a basic mis-parsing of unexceptional text.

Comment: It's important both to cite the source of a quotation (which allows it to be verified) **and** to transcribe it accurately in the first place.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a quotation which is mistranscribed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*May paints* is nonsensical, and *George O,* looks suspicious. I believe it's actually

> George O. May points out the following

Notice the period after *O*, capitalized *May*, and *points* rather than *paints*.

Where *George O. May* is a person, possibly [this one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_O._May). This man *[points out](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/point+out)*, i.e. specifies, a list of people or businesses who issue or read financial statements.

Comment: Thanks Kevin you are right I put comma instead of period. Thanks for your answer.